# Why is navigation destination lost when I launch a action for the second time with navigation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I use navigation in my project.

The Image 1 will be displayed when the app start, I click Next button in Image 1, the Image 2 will be displayed, then I click Back button in Image 2, the image 1 will be displayed again.

Now I click Next button in Image 1 again, the app crash, I get the error *'navigation destination com.example.myapplication:id/actionTwo is unknown to this NavController'*, why?

Why can't  `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(OneFrDirections.actionTwo())` be launched for the second time ?

You can download the test code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ad47eqi4iwig5v/MyNAV.zip?dl=0

**my.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my"
    app:startDestination="@+id/One">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/One"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.OneFr"
        android:label="One">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionTwo"
            app:destination="@id/Two" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Two"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.TwoFr"
        android:label="Two">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionOne"
            app:destination="@id/One" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**OneFr.kt**

```
class OneFr : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false)


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

         view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNext).setOnClickListener {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(OneFrDirections.actionTwo())
        }

    }

}
```

**TwoFr.kt**

```
class TwoFr : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, container, false)


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Handle back button press
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnBack).setOnClickListener {
            fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
        }

    }

}
```

**one.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**two.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: Instead of `fragmentManager?.popBackStack()` , try `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack()`

Comment: please award bounty since the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `fragmentManager?.popBackStack()` , try

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack()
```

Use `NavigationController` for back stack since `NavController` is managing navigation, manually popping fragments would cause errors in `NavController`.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works well, but I wonder why my code work well when I launch for the first time and failed for the second time.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works well, but I wonder why my code is work when I launch for the first time and failed for the second time.

Comment: @HelloCW `NavController` is responsible for handling transactions, I don't know the details but doing transactions on your own is going to break `NavController` at some point, like in your case

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that `popBackStack()`  is dangerous operation? sometimes it maybe cause error.

Comment: I think `popBackStack()` is take OneFr fragment  from background to foreground when  OneFr fragment hasn't taken back by system.   If  the  OneFr fragment is taken back by system, `'popBackStack()`  will cause error, right?

Comment: `popBackStack()` just removes the top fragment so it shouldn't throw any exceptions, I think `NavController` still thinks it is on second fragment when you pop second fragment directly from `FragmentManager`

Comment: Will OneFr fragment be destroy when TwoFr  fragment is loaded?

Comment: @HelloCW yes thats what pop does

Comment: The app will crash  when TwoFr invoke `popBackStack()`  if OneFr fragment has been destroy, right?

Comment: @HelloCW if you do it from `NavComtroller` it won't crash, however if you pop using `FragmentManager` and then use`NavController` , it will crash

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for navigating:

From FrOne to FrTwo:

```
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.actionTwo)
```

From FrTwo to FrOne:

```
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.actionOne)
```